# Grant a login access to administrator in professional edition

Tags: configuration

I am a system admin. In lead object page layout i have given read only access to some fields. But i am able to add and edit data in those read only field. As a system administrator can i log in as a another user in professional edition?

Answer (score 2):

As per the [doc](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=granting_login_access.htm),

> Granting administrator access available in: Enterprise, Performance, Unlimited, Developer, and Database.com Editions

Professional Edition does not support this feature.

An [Idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000ip96AAA) for this is available on IdeaExchange